# usage of jdom2 within eclipse plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I used the JDOM2 XML parser before in a normal and stand alone java projects building it with fatjar. Now I tried using it within a Eclipse Plugin but I’m unable to do so.
I tried to add it to my plugin by copying it to a lib folder and adding it in the plugin.xml in the runtime tab in the classpath. After doing so the plugin doesn’t even start any more

Could not create the view: Plug-in *** was unable to load class ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new plugin project -> Plug-in from existing JAR archives (From the comment of eactor)

Add the unresolved jar

Export as plugin

Search for the plugin in main plugin project

Add it in dependencies

Comment: New-> other -> Plug-in Development>Plug-in from existing JAR archives